# How to notify user even when application is in background

Tags: android, background

I am currently trying to notify the user of a change in the app even when the application is in the background.

I've currently got a plain AlertDialog set up to notify the user of this specific change, but I don't think actually shows when the user has it on the background.

Is there a specific function that me to show some kind of notification (Toast or Dialog) to show the user a message even when the application is running in the background?

Comment: What do you mean by "the application is in the background"? Like, when you use an app, and then you minimize it?

Comment: Yes, when the person uses the 'back' button, but not terminate it.

Comment: So, you want an exact moment when the application is transfered to the background, or when something happens in the background?

Comment: When something happens in the background.

Comment: One question: What will cause this notification to the user? I mean, if your app is in background, nothing will change since it is in background... Which event will happen? Is there a service running or are your registered from a Broadcasted Intent? Please, share more details.. otherwise, it will be impossible to help you more

Answer (score 1):

From background your best bet is to show user a notification or a Toast which can even work from a Service. For showing a dialog, you need to have a foreground Activity. You can even launch an Activity if you want from the background but, I guess that might get a bit intrusive.